# twilio js client trying to load from localhost

Tags: twilio

I am playing around with twilio javascript client, I am just loading the library like in the docs:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.1/twilio.min.js"></script>
```

But what happen is my browser show the following error (yes I am testing it locally):

```
GET http://localhost:57183/libs/twiliojs/refs/7ed9035/twilio.js 410 (Gone)
```

With initiator:

```
twilio.min.js:3
```

Why is that? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I just tried it on my localhost, seemed to work fine. Are you using a virtual host or just `localhost/` via wamp or some other windows web stack?

Comment: I am testing within VisualStudio2013 with IISexpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the twilio.js earlier in the page head solved the issue. I erroneously put references to the twilio client api in a js script loading before twilio.js, but those references were inside an angularjs controller, so I would have not expected them to be evaluated till execution. 
But nevertheless it's correct to load the library earlier.

Answer (score 2):

if your site is not going to be served via HTTPS - you can safely change those two slashes at the beginning into ("//" => "http://") and all should work just fine for You.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.1/twilio.min.js"></script>
```

(as long as you are still online while testing locally)

if you want to test your site when you are offline you need to download the scipt and put it for emample in "js" folder in your document root directory and include it from there:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/twilio.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you mean online=test while having internet connection. Yes I have. But I have not published on a server and dns name the website. It's just running on my development box, hence the "localhost:57183". If I try adding "http:" nothing change.

Comment: @webdev-dan The initial JS file is loading fine, its the JS file that `twilio.min.js` calls is the issue.

Comment: well ...i had a second look now - and it seems that problem might be with your server software, try wampServer - I just tried it - everything works fine

Comment: @FruityP yes, you're right - i noticed it - but checked the code and it really should work - url is taken from script tag - but here somehow it gets messed and changed into localhost - i tried it on my localhost and it works fine.